# using the following equations in code

Tags: ios, objective-c, math

in my app i want to calculate the distance between two points that has a latitude and a longitude. i managed to get the equations used to calculate it from this website (http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/haversine/) and here is the equations:

```
dlon = lon2 - lon1 
dlat = lat2 - lat1 
a = (sin(dlat/2))^2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * (sin(dlon/2))^2 
c = 2 * atan2( sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a) ) 
d = R * c (where R is the radius of the Earth
```

so i translate them as code, here it is:

```
float distanceLongitude = lon2 - lon1;
float distanceLatitude = lat2 - lat1;
float a = powf(sinf((distanceLatitude/2)), 2) + cosf(lat1) * cosf(lat2) * powf((sinf(distanceLongitude/2)),2);
float c = 2 * atan2f(sqrtf(a), sqrtf(1-a));
float d = 6373 * c; //6373 radius of earth
```

i tried the code with the following coordinates: 
lat1 = 33.854025 lon1 = 35.506923
lat2 = 33.856835 lon2 = 35.506324

according to the website, the results are 0.317 km or 0.197 miles. however, my code's output is giving me 18.143757. how can i fix that? (please check the converter in the website to know what i'm talking about.

Note: d should be the final result.

Comment: I'm not completely familiar with this field, but your latitude and longitude are in units of degrees ... shouldn't your trig functions also take in degrees?  i believe that the sines/cosines in objective-c take radians.

Comment: you're right, i know how to convert the sin/cos from radians to degrees but how do i convert the atan2?

Comment: @user2176995: There is no need to convert the result of `atan2f`. It is in radians, and you want it in radians. Multiplying radians by a radius produces distance with the proper scale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why wouldn't you use the Apple API to calculate this distance? You could just perform something like this:

```
 CLLocation *locA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat1 longitude:long1];

 CLLocation *locB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat2 longitude:long2];

 CLLocationDistance distance = [locA distanceFromLocation:locB];
```

Note that CLLLocationDistance it's just a typedef to a float, and the distance variable will have the value in meters.

Answer (score 3):

The input to the `sinf` and `cosf` routines is in radians. You must convert angles from degrees to radians before calling them. To do this, multiply the angles by π/180º.

Answer (score 2):

The latitude and lingitude is (most probably) given in decimal degrees, such as 52.09878 and 10.897934. But the sinf etc functions use radiants.

Try converting your `distanceLongitude` and `distanceLatitude` to radiants and then continue with a = ...

```
radiantLongitudeDistance = degreeLongitudeDistance * M_PI / 180.0
```